# Setting the maximum width of a table

Tags: html, css, width, html-table, max

I'm trying to set the maximum width of a table, but it doesn't seem to be working. If a word inside the table is too long, it automatically expands the width of the table. How do I stop that from happening, and instead have the word that's too long go to the next line?

```css
<style>table {
  max-width: 300px;
}

table,
td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

</style>
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div> hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Add `max-width` to `td` as well. https://jsfiddle.net/2kcc59o6/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to make your max-width to work, you need to set the CSS property `table-layout: fixed;` on the table and use `width`, not `max-width`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Answer (score 0):

Add the following rule your css section.

```
div{
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    max-width: 300px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting max-width inside the div solves the problem.

```css
<style>
table,td {
border: 1px solid red;
}
div {
border: 1px solid blue;
word-wrap: break-word;
max-width: 300px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<table>

<tr>
<td>
<div> hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello </div>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`word-wrap: break-word;` will work if you have width assigned to the container, you are applying this property to. Thus, you will have to assign `width:100px;` or desired width to `div` tag.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
         width: 100px; /* this will limit the length of the word to 100px */
         border: 1px solid blue;
         word-wrap: break-word;
        }
</style>
```