# How can I truncate text in fixed-width table cells?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table, width, truncate

I have a table with 3 table cells. My goal is to set a fixed width for each. The td in the middle should also cut the text if its to long for the td and show dots if the text is too long. (text-truncate)

I tried different possibilities (table-fixed, max-width etc.), but it still doesn't work. Maybe someone can help me.

```css
/* table styles added by community for demonstration */
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  background: pink;
}

.cut-text {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <td style="width: 10%">XXX</td>
  <td style="width: 70%" class="cut-text">LOOOOOOOONG TEXT LOOOOOOOONG TEXT LOOOOOOOONG TEXT LOOOOOOOONG TEXT LOOOOOOOONG TEXT </td>
  <td style="width: 20%">XXX</td>
</table>
```

The normal Table looks like this:

[image: Normal table without a long text]

And if the text in the middle is to long I want to show dots like this (I achieve this with a div in the middle cell. Then I set the div width and added the class "cut-text". But then there is no third cell.)

[image: Table with a long text (here i miss the third td)]

Maybe someone can help me.

Kind regards.

Comment: Your code actually works just fine. You need to effectively limit the width of the table to see it (or add enough text to the middle column).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting the maximum width of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063418/setting-the-maximum-width-of-a-table)

Comment: Thank you! Its a little bit confusing. Your suggestions works perfectly, but just for the body. When i add a thead to the table, every row has the size of 1/3 of the width, no matter what i add to the style. Anyway, withouth my thead it works, thats what i need. Thank you!